# Android - Start Intent after download using DownloadManager

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

What I have is multiple buttons. Using if-else statements, I download a file to that corresponding button. Now, I also define what class to open via intent in the if-else statement. I need to have it so that it will begin downloading the file and then start a new activity. I used to do this with an AsyncTask, and start the new intent in the onPostExecute, but I decided it's better to use DownloadManager. So, you may be confused. So I'll explain through my code...

So, here I'm setting it all up:

```
 BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                            DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                                .getInt(columnIndex)) {
                            String uriString = c
                                    .getString(c
                                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Ok. Now, in my if-else I declare the url to download, as well as setting a string equal to a class, and another string equal to the output file:

```
if (andy != null){
                className = "com.cydeon.plasmamodz.Softkeys";
                fileName = "batterymod.zip";
                dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Request req = new Request(
                        Uri.parse("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/gfukrwqy4xqrnj9/Android.zip"));
                req.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                        fileName);
                enqueue = dm.enqueue(req);
            }
```

Ok. So all works good. Now, my showDownload:

```
public void showDownload(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
    startActivity(i);
```

Good. Now, it downloads. So, now that's it's downloading, I need to start a new activity. And, I've researched and tried some stuff, but nothing works. As you saw, I already set a class inside the string. I have this code which I used in the onPostExecute, so I know it works fine:

```
        try {
          Intent openNewIntent = new Intent(Bmod.this, Class.forName(className) );
          startActivity( openNewIntent );
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
```

So, I'll repeat what I want. I want to download a file, and then, after executing the download, start a new activity. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit - Here's an updated code:

```
    public void showDownload(View view) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Download complete";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
    try {
          Intent openNewIntent = new Intent(Bmod.this, Class.forName(className) );
          startActivity( openNewIntent );
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the startActivity() call in the broadcast receiver's onReceive() so that the activity is started when your receiver is notified the download is complete.

Comment: Ok. I don't want it to wait for the download to finish before starting the class. I want it to download while the rest of the app is running.

Comment: Ah well then don't do the showDownload() just launch your activity. The DownloadManager will run in the background and your receiver will get called when the download is done. You don't have to show the download for it to download. If you launch the DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS activity then that activity takes control.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work for some reason... Check updated op for the code I used.